# amcharts showing incorrect date value in category axis which is not present in dataProvider

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am plotting area chart using amcharts, the x-axis data date values range from 08/01/2014 to 08/30/2014. But the graph displaying the x-axis values from 07/31/2014 onwards. This issue is found only in latest version of windows Firefox and chrome. Attaching the screen shot of the graph plotted and the dataProvider values below.

`dataProvider = [{
            "value": 0,
            "date": "2014-08-01"
        },
        {
            "value": 17
            "date": "2014-08-02"
        },
        {
            "value": 24
            "date": "2014-08-03"
        },
        {
            "value": 26
            "date": "2014-08-04"
        },
       ....
]`

[image: Plotted chart]

How could I solve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this. Could we (amcharts) get full source code. It would be best if you could address directly to our support.

Comment: @zeroin Please see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fk6e5vzj/6/). The categoryBalloon value also shows 07/31/2014.

Comment: @zeroin This issue is able to reproduce in windows chrome(v 37.0.2062.120) and firefox version (v32)

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce this in any browser. Try setting dataDateFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD" on the chart instance ( you must set dataDateFormat or use Date Objects instead)

Comment: Thanks zeroin. Fixed the issue by setting dataDateFormat on chart instance.

Answer (score 6):

I updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fk6e5vzj/9/):

The issue is the TIMEZONE. Amcharts appears to be taking the given time as UTC and converting back to your local time.

In the fiddle I modified the first few data points to

```
2014-08-01T10:00:01
```

next to 8AM next to 7AM (I am in California) and voila! date appears as expected in the balloons.